# how can i stop module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, exit

I have a simple code.

1. start button press -> infinite loop and application clear
2. stop button press -> infinite loop is stop by control c event

but I want to stop `test2.py` using other way not control c event.

because I made `.exe` file using `pyinstaller` by no console.

so control c event is not working...

how can I stop `test2` module?

**test.py :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import test2
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from win32api import GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent
from win32con import CTRL_C_EVENT


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Start", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)            
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text())
        test2.main(app)

    def stop(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text())
        GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)

def main():
    global app
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**test2.py :**

```
def main(app):
    while 1:
        print "infinite loop"
        app.processEvents()
```

Comment: can you not just raise any exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple flag:

**test2.py**:

```
active = False

def main(app):
    global active
    active = True
    while active:
        print "infinite loop"
        app.processEvents()
```

**test1.py**:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...

    def stop(self):
        ...
        test2.active = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Raise any exception.  If your goal is to mimic `Ctrl-C`, use `KeyboardInterrupt`.  That is, replace the line

```
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
```

with

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt('You pressed the stop button.')
```

in `test.py`.

Comment: no.... i want to stop test2 using another way if i pressed stop button. my code already stop test2.

Comment: @Somputer what you just said doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255513/how-to-generate-keyboard-interrupt-in-pythonw-exe

Comment: @Somputer that doesn't help me.  and, in general, it's best not to post two questions about the same issue.  these questions should be combined.